# I can't get my value to update using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

So I am learning WPF by making a yatzee game, and I'm getting somewhere. But now I can not understand why I my "current roll" counter won't update in the View. I made the Dices work, and the roll dices button gives my dices new values - and this is updated in the view. But my "Current roll" variable will not. This is what I've done so far.

```
// CurrentRoll.cs
    public class CurrentRoll : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int _roll;

    public int Roll
    {
        get { return _roll; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _roll)
            { 
            _roll = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Roll");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Then this is my DiceModelView. When I hit my "Roll Dices" button I get new values on all my dices as long as they are left unchecked. I also increment the _currentRoll variable, and only allow new rolls as long as _currentRoll still is less than 3. This logic works, the variable works, but it's representation in the View does not. I've also changed its initial value to other values just to see that my binding works, and it does.

```
public class DiceModelView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Die _die;
    public CurrentRoll _currentRoll;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Die> myDices { get; set; }
    public ICommand RollCommand { get; set; }

    public DiceModelView()
    {
        myDices = new ObservableCollection<Die>()
        {
            new Die { Id = 0, Roll = 0, Checked = false },
            new Die { Id = 1, Roll = 0, Checked = false },
            new Die { Id = 2, Roll = 0, Checked = false },
            new Die { Id = 3, Roll = 0, Checked = false },
            new Die { Id = 4, Roll = 0, Checked = false }
        };
        _currentRoll = new CurrentRoll();
        _currentRoll._roll = 0;
        RollCommand = new Command (executeMethod, canexecuteMethod);
    }

    public bool canexecuteMethod(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void executeMethod(object parameter)
    {
        var r = new Random();
        if (_currentRoll._roll < 3)
        {
            foreach (Die d in myDices)
            {
                if (d.Checked == false)
                {
                    d.Roll = r.Next(1, 7);
                }
            }
        }
        _currentRoll._roll++;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public Die die
    {
        get { return _die; }
        set { _die = value; }
    }

    public CurrentRoll currentRoll
    {
        get { return _currentRoll; }
        set { _currentRoll = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("currentRoll");
        }
    }
```

[image: How my application is now, in this example I set _currentRoll._roll to 111 just to be sure that it works. I've not rolled any dices as the aforementioned value is more than 3.]

Finally, this is the XAML code I use:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:DiceModelView/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding currentRoll.Roll, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <ListView x:Name="DiceView" ItemsSource="{Binding myDices}" Width="500" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Roll}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="Roll the dices!" Command="{Binding RollCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Unrelated: You have a *public* field and a *public* Property backed by that field. And you access the field directly *and* through the Property. This *will* backfire in your face sooner or later.

Comment: @Fildor: Why "unrelated"? That's exactly the problem here :)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Oh, I didn't expect it to actually completely solve the issue.

Comment: Not quite sure how I ended up doing that, I did it the right way with the Die class. But good catch from both of you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update the `Roll` property, not the `_role` field.

`_roll` should be private anyway.

Just think about it: You are raising the property changed event in the property setter, so this only get's executed when you set the value of the property.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! The fact that the _roll was public was the root cause, intellisens kept telling me to go with _currentRoll._roll rather than _currentRoll.Roll.

Comment: @Tom: Your comment makes no sense to me. Neither `Roll` nor `_roll` were private in your class, at least not from the code you gave us.

Comment: Typo. I meant public, sorry. Making it private did the trick.